# What needs to set for Configuration of a FeignClient

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to override the default configuration for one of my `FeignClient`. However, there is a mismatch in the documentation so I don't know which one I should follow.

In the section of `Feign` for `Spring Cloud` document (link [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign)), it says the following regarding the configuration.

> The FooConfiguration has to be @Configuration but take care that it is not in a @ComponentScan for the main application context, otherwise it will be used for every @FeignClient

However, I see a contradicting warning in the reference documentation for `Spring Cloud OpenFeign` (link [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults)), where it says

> FooConfiguration does not need to be annotated with @Configuration. However, if it is, then take care to exclude it from any @ComponentScan that would otherwise include this configuration as it will become the default source for feign.Decoder, feign.Encoder, feign.Contract, etc., when specified.

So which one should I follow? How to check if my configuration class is the one picked up for my `FeignClient`?

Comment: Yes, the 2nd one is true and we need to fix the first one since it does not need to be `@Configuration`.

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks a lot. It clears up my confusion now.